# Android accelerometer: SensorManager.DATA_X is deprecated - now what?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have written an accelerometer app (for learning purposes) using some of the suggestions from StackOverflow. Everything works fine but I get the "SensorManager.DATA_X is deprecated" message as a warning in my code:

```
// setup the textviews for displaying the accelerations
mAccValueViews[SensorManager.DATA_X] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accele_x_value);
mAccValueViews[SensorManager.DATA_Y] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accele_y_value);
mAccValueViews[SensorManager.DATA_Z] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accele_z_value);
```

I have tried searching here and elsewhere for what I should do instead of using "SensorManager.DATA_X" but I can't seem to find any instructions.

The official guide says to use "sensor" instead but I can't figure out how!

If anyone can suggest what the new "official" way of doing the above is then I would be very grateful.

***Edit***
After re-reading the documentation (properly this time!) I noticed that "SensorManager.DATA_X" just returns an int which is the index of the X value in the array returned by onSensorChanged(int, float[]). I was able to change the above code to this, which works perfectly and without any deprecated warnings:

```
// setup the textviews for displaying the accelerations
    mAccValueViews[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accele_x_value);
    mAccValueViews[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accele_y_value);
    mAccValueViews[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accele_z_value);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear on it, create your sensor:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;

mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null){
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}
```

And there is your [Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html), register a listener to use it:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

You can then use OnSensorChanged to get [values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values):

```
  @Override
  public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
    float xaccel = event.values[0];
    // Do something with this sensor value.
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have been following that proceadure for my onSensorChanged method, however, later in the code that I am re-using, in the onCreate method, the code I posted above appears. I would like to replace the "SensorManager.DATA_X" with some reference for the "event.values[i]" defined in the onSensorChanged method, but I can't seem to do this!

Comment: I guess you will have to initialise them with 0 and set them in the first `onSensorChanged` event. I reckon it fires within milliseconds after registering the listener.

Comment: Thanks again. Well your first comment about reading the documentation was spot on. When I reread the documentation *properly* this time - I noticed that "SensorManager.DATA_X" returns an int which is the index of the X value in the array returned by onSensorChanged(int, float[]). Since these are only index values I was able to replace mAccValueViews[SensorManager.DATA_X] with mAccValueViews[0]....etc....