# Detect Shake for 8 Sec

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am using Accelerometer for the purpose of shake detection but i want if a user will shake their devices for 8 Sec then the resulting method will be triggered.
With my current code a can able to detect the shake but i want a 8sec timer too.
My Current Code is

```
public class AccelerometerManager {
    private static Context aContext=null;

    /** Accuracy configuration */
    private static float threshold  = 15.0f;
    private static int interval     = 200;

    private static Sensor sensor;
    private static SensorManager sensorManager;
    // you could use an OrientationListener array instead
    // if you plans to use more than one listener
    private static AccelerometerListener listener;

    /** indicates whether or not Accelerometer Sensor is supported */
    private static Boolean supported;
    /** indicates whether or not Accelerometer Sensor is running */
    private static boolean running = false;

    /**
     * Returns true if the manager is listening to orientation changes
     */
    public static boolean isListening() {
        return running;
    }

    /**
     * Unregisters listeners
     */
    public static void stopListening() {
        running = false;
        try {
            if (sensorManager != null && sensorEventListener != null) {
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if at least one Accelerometer sensor is available
     */
    public static boolean isSupported(Context context) {
        aContext = context;
        if (supported == null) {
            if (aContext != null) {


                sensorManager = (SensorManager) aContext.
                        getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

                // Get all sensors in device
                List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(
                        Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

                supported = new Boolean(sensors.size() > 0);



            } else {
                supported = Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        }
        return supported;
    }

    /**
     * Configure the listener for shaking
     * @param threshold
     *             minimum acceleration variation for considering shaking
     * @param interval
     *             minimum interval between to shake events
     */
    public static void configure(int threshold, int interval) {
        AccelerometerManager.threshold = threshold;
        AccelerometerManager.interval = interval;
    }

    /**
     * Registers a listener and start listening
     * @param accelerometerListener
     *             callback for accelerometer events
     */
    public static void startListening( AccelerometerListener accelerometerListener )
    {

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) aContext.
                getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Take all sensors in device
        List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(
                Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        if (sensors.size() > 0) {

            sensor = sensors.get(0);

            // Register Accelerometer Listener
            running = sensorManager.registerListener(
                    sensorEventListener, sensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

            listener = accelerometerListener;
        }


    }

    /**
     * Configures threshold and interval
     * And registers a listener and start listening
     * @param accelerometerListener
     *             callback for accelerometer events
     * @param threshold
     *             minimum acceleration variation for considering shaking
     * @param interval
     *             minimum interval between to shake events
     */
    public static void startListening(
            AccelerometerListener accelerometerListener,
            int threshold, int interval) {
        configure(threshold, interval);
        startListening(accelerometerListener);
    }

    /**
     * The listener that listen to events from the accelerometer listener
     */
    private static SensorEventListener sensorEventListener =
            new SensorEventListener() {

                private long now = 0;
                private long timeDiff = 0;
                private long lastUpdate = 0;
                private long lastShake = 0;

                private float x = 0;
                private float y = 0;
                private float z = 0;
                private float lastX = 0;
                private float lastY = 0;
                private float lastZ = 0;
                private float force = 0;

                public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

                public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                    // use the event timestamp as reference
                    // so the manager precision won't depends
                    // on the AccelerometerListener implementation
                    // processing time
                    now = event.timestamp;

                    x = event.values[0];
                    y = event.values[1];
                    z = event.values[2];

                    // if not interesting in shake events
                    // just remove the whole if then else block
                    if (lastUpdate == 0) {
                        lastUpdate = now;
                        lastShake = now;
                        lastX = x;
                        lastY = y;
                        lastZ = z;
                        Toast.makeText(aContext,"No Motion detected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        timeDiff = now - lastUpdate;

                        if (timeDiff > 0) {

                    /*force = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ)
                                / timeDiff;*/
                            force = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ);

                            if (Float.compare(force, threshold) >0 ) {

                                if (now - lastShake >= 8000000000l) {

                                    // trigger shake event
                                    listener.onShake(force);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(aContext,"No Motion detected",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                lastShake = now;
                            }
                            lastX = x;
                            lastY = y;
                            lastZ = z;
                            lastUpdate = now;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(aContext,"No Motion detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                    // trigger change event
                    listener.onAccelerationChanged(x, y, z);
                }

            };

}
```

Comment: what is problem in above code?  is shake event detected or not?

Comment: shake is detected but i want a continues shake for 8 sec

Comment: Means, do you want detection after user continues shake phone for 8 seconds?

Comment: Yes this is what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code for detecting continues shake for 8 second.

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;


/**
 * Listener that detects shake gesture.
 */
public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {


  /** Minimum movement force to consider. */
  private static final int MIN_FORCE = 10;

  /**
   * Minimum times in a shake gesture that the direction of movement needs to
   * change.
   */
  private static final int MIN_DIRECTION_CHANGE = 3;

  /** Maximum pause between movements. */
  private static final int MAX_PAUSE_BETHWEEN_DIRECTION_CHANGE = 1000;

  /** Minimum allowed time for shake gesture. */
  private static final int MIN_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SHAKE = 8000; // 8 seconds

  /** Time when the gesture started. */
  private long mFirstDirectionChangeTime = 0;

  /** Time when the last movement started. */
  private long mLastDirectionChangeTime;

  /** How many movements are considered so far. */
  private int mDirectionChangeCount = 0;

  /** The last x position. */
  private float lastX = 0;

  /** The last y position. */
  private float lastY = 0;

  /** The last z position. */
  private float lastZ = 0;

  /** OnShakeListener that is called when shake is detected. */
  private OnShakeListener mShakeListener;

  /**
   * Interface for shake gesture.
   */
  public interface OnShakeListener {

    /**
     * Called when shake gesture is detected.
     */
    void onShake();
  }

  public void setOnShakeListener(OnShakeListener listener) {
    mShakeListener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
    // get sensor data
    float x = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
    float y = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
    float z = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

    // calculate movement
    float totalMovement = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ);

    if (totalMovement > MIN_FORCE) {

      // get time
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

      // store first movement time
      if (mFirstDirectionChangeTime == 0) {
        mFirstDirectionChangeTime = now;
        mLastDirectionChangeTime = now;
      }

      // check if the last movement was not long ago
      long lastChangeWasAgo = now - mLastDirectionChangeTime;
      if (lastChangeWasAgo < MAX_PAUSE_BETHWEEN_DIRECTION_CHANGE) {

        // store movement data
        mLastDirectionChangeTime = now;
        mDirectionChangeCount++;

        // store last sensor data 
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        lastZ = z;

        // check how many movements are so far
        if (mDirectionChangeCount >= MIN_DIRECTION_CHANGE) {

          // check total duration
          long totalDuration = now - mFirstDirectionChangeTime;
          if (totalDuration >= MIN_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SHAKE) {
            mShakeListener.onShake();
            resetShakeParameters();
          }
        }

      } else {
        resetShakeParameters();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Resets the shake parameters to their default values.
   */
  private void resetShakeParameters() {
    mFirstDirectionChangeTime = 0;
    mDirectionChangeCount = 0;
    mLastDirectionChangeTime = 0;
    lastX = 0;
    lastY = 0;
    lastZ = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
  }

}
```

Add below code in your activity:

```
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;

  private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;


    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener();   

    mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

      public void onShake() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Shake detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

Register for shake listener in `onResume` method and unregister it in `onPause` method as below.

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onPause();
  }
```

Comment: hey @Priyank SensorManager.DATA_X has deprecated any alternatives?

Comment: @RaunakPandey check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687480/android-accelerometer-sensormanager-data-x-is-deprecated-now-what